# I do not get the "back" arrow in Master Detail Page

Tags: xamarin.forms, master-detail

With the standard (template) implementation of Master Detail Page, I do not get a back button when I call the side menu. 
Standard implementation looks like this:

```
<NavigationPage>
            <x:Arguments>
                <local:DetailPage1/>
            </x:Arguments>
</NavigationPage>
```

But when I implement navigation in this way:

```
MainPage = new NavigationPage(new MainPage());
```

i get the button back

Why does this happen and why I do not get a button with the standard (template) implementation? Thanks

screenshot with a running button at the bottom

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rYkws.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all - the menu (master page) should not have a back button.

[image]

From the [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/navigation/master-detail-page):

> A MasterDetailPage is designed to be a root page, and using it as a
>   child page in other page types could result in unexpected and
>   inconsistent behavior. In addition, it's recommended that the master
>   page of a MasterDetailPage should always be a ContentPage instance,
>   and that the detail page should only be populated with TabbedPage,
>   NavigationPage, and ContentPage instances. This will help to ensure a
>   consistent user experience across all platforms.

If your `MasterDetailPage` is not a root page and it is wrapped by a `NavigationPage` you may see the back arrow.

That should answer your question.
 Additional details and restrictions are listed in the [same official doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/navigation/master-detail-page).